# How does entanglement work for relativistic particles?

Tags: special-relativity, quantum-entanglement, time-dilation

Say I created a pair of entangled atoms, suppose if I were to accelerate one of the atom close to the speed of light while the other remains at rest. Can I still accurately predict the outcome? I know distance does not really affect these entangled particles but what about time dilation?

Comment: I actually had the same question, and I am wondering if this could cause a retrocausal effect if the part that experienced less time were affected.  Would that cause an effect back in time an equivalent amount of time for the “older” particle, back when they were the same age?  By the way, I think the question is really good, just the grammar was off a bit, so I edited it and gave it an upvote!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An entangled system is a single system described by a single wavefunction. The whole point of entanglement is that the wavefunction cannot simply be split into separate parts for the two particles. It is not two separate particles that are somehow slightly mixed, it is a single system.

So when you say:

> suppose if I were to accelerate one of the atoms

this is not possible because the entangled system is not simply two separate atoms. If you interact with the system in such a way as to affect only one atom you will destroy the entanglement.

The entangled particles can certainly be moving relative to each other at some constant speed, and that's fine because we understand how to handle relativistic systems in quantum mechanics. There is no problem with this. It is interacting with the system in order to accelerate just part of it that is the problem.

You can achieve something like this simply by preparing your entangled pair in a gravitational field. For example if you do [the EPR experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPR_paradox) and arrange for one of the particles to vertically upwards while the other goes vertically downwards then because the Earth's gravitational field changes with height it will cause a different time dilation for the two particles. I'm not sure how well this effect is understood theoretically. However [the recent experiments by Chinese scientists](https://www.newscientist.com/article/2134843-chinese-satellite-beats-distance-record-for-quantum-entanglement/) show that entanglement can be preserved for photons sent up to a satellite.